# Сложение в JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Почему id2 складывает значения, а не числа?

```
var id = $(this).attr('id'); //id это число, допустим 100
var id1 = id - 1; // = 99
var id2 = id + 1; // = 1001
var id3 = id - -1; // = 101
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var id = Number(    $(this).attr('id')    );
```

Необходимо делать конвертацию, потому что id остается строкой после присваивания из свойства. При операции сложения происходит конкатенация строк, а при операции разности происходит конвертация в число и вычисляется разность, поскольку нет операции разности для строк.

Comment: эквивалентно:

    var id = +$(this).attr('id');
    var id = ~~$(this).attr('id');

Comment: очень доходчивый ответ, спасибо

Comment: Спасибо ОГРОМНОЕ. Зарегистрировался только для того, чтобы поблагодарить! Реально запарился искать, как вывести именно сумму переменных.

Answer (score 2):

[Преобразование типов, toString и valueOf](http://learn.javascript.ru/object-conversion) 
почитать полезно.

Comment: спасибо за материал